# Searching Path through grid in 2-dimensions with condition

Tags: python

Lets Assume we have a Grid {a,b} with entries |b-a| for n <= a,b < N  and |b-a| > 0.

How can I design a path through all entries, where I visit the highest values of b-a first?

The problem arises for me when we coming across the border a==b, because I need to visit all entries and at that border I have to go back.

My first idea was the following:

```
paths = {}
for a in range(n,N-1):
    for b in range(a+1,N):
        if b-a not in paths:
            paths[b-a] = [(a,b)]
        else:
            paths[b-a] += [(a,b)]

for p in reversed(list(paths.key())):
    for q in paths[p]:
        visit(q)
```

The Problem is that this solution takes far too much memory for big N. I was thinking of a similar solution which uses only iterators and not a dictionary, but I am not able to reformulate the problem properly for using iterators.

Any suggestions?

//edit: I solved it, for anyone who is interested:

```
class period_iter:
    def __init__(self,t0,t1):
        self.t0 = t0
        self.t1 = t1
    def __iter__(self):
        self.i = -1
        self.j = 0 
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i > self.j:
            self.i =  0   
            self.j += 1
        if self.j == (self.t1 - self.t0):
            raise StopIteration
        ti = t0 + self.i
        tf = self.t1-(self.j-self.i)
        return (ti,tf,tf-ti)
```